# execute a ajax call before sign out - devise & rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I am trying to gather some user stats and want to execute an ajax call so log some data before user is signed out of the application.

I have the below code

```
    document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      createStats();
    });
```

There is an ajax call in createStats function and its `POST` method call. The problem i am facing is the user session is signed out first and then the ajax call is processed which make the `CSRF Token` invalid & no further processing happens.

Is there a way i can execute an ajax call and on complete sign-out the user.

I also tried to trigger the sign out link in ajax:success like `$('#sign-out').trigger('click')` but it did not trigger.

Any help in this will be really appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you not combine them in the control portion of the call? So when you make your AJAX call to your controller, you log the data and then on completion sign the user out there? Or does something need to happen on the page before that happens?

Comment: Can you just create the status in the same method for signout? Just put the code in there before ending the session?

Comment: Hi @Keith are you suggesting to use devise helper method `sign_out :user` in my custom controller, how would you redirect the user to the sign in page after that?

Comment: hi @Doughtz, sorry i did not understand, would you be able to explain what you mean by sample code?

Comment: Can't you do a Response.Redirect("http://www.loginpage.com");

Comment: That sign out button leads to a controller action, right? If so, just put in ruby code inside that controller action to save the stats before the ruby code to sign the user out is run.

Comment: @Doughtz signout currently is a logout link generated by using devise helper, its not going to a controller

Comment: It should be. You should have a SessionsController. Most likely located at app/controllers/users/ if your user model is User

Comment: @Doughtz, sorry i meant its not going to a custom controller, how do i convert the link generated by using <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'sign-out', id: 'sign-out' do %> to send a ajax request, as i need to pass values stored in a few javascript variables to the stats method

Comment: How about create your own link that executes a post to your own controller method. Once that is done, then use devise's sign_out helper method and then redirect_to some other page

Comment: @Doughtz, that sounds logical, would that be a elegant solution just trying to understand is devise already provides a solution to something like this and that i dont redo something already there

Comment: Yeah it's good. Devise has those helper methods for situations like this. So people can do what works for their web app. Another option, is you can pass Rails' CSRF token with your current post as a header. The reason you're getting the CSRF is not because the user logged out, but because you're executing a POST request without the token, and Rails requires it. I'll post an answer to edit your current ajax if you post the code for your ajax call.